# Python sort a dict by multiple values on multiples levels

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

I have a python list that i would to sort by multiple keys.

```
datas = {
    '123': {
        'name': 'Adam',
        'nbgamesTot': 4, 
        'winrateTot': '100.00', 
        'D1': {
            'nbwins': 4, 
            'nbgames': 4, 
            'winrate': 100
        },
        'D2': 'etc...',
    },
    '456': {
        'name': 'Mark', 
        'nbgamesTot': 4, 
        'winrateTot': '25.00', 
        'D1': {
            'nbwins': 1, 
            'nbgames': 4, 
            'winrate': 25
        },
        'D2': 'etc...',
    }, 
    '789': {
        'name': 'Yoko', 
        'nbgamesTot': 4, 
        'winrateTot': '25.00', 
        'D1': {
            'nbwins': 1, 
            'nbgames': 4, 
            'winrate': 25
        },
        'D2': 'etc...',
    }
}
```

But when i tried :

```
sorted_datas = sorted(datas.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1]['D1']['nbgames'], x[1]['nbgamesTot'], x[1]['winrateTot']), reverse=True)
```

I have :
Yoko : 1/4 - 1/4 - 25
Mark : 1/4 - 1/4 - 25
Adam : 4/4 - 4/4 - 100

Any idea of what is wrong ?
maybe itemgetter would be a better idea? in this case how to do?

And second question :  if I want to sort in different order according to the keys? (ex : nbgames desc, nbgamestot asc, and winrate desc ?

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: There are syntax errors in your assignment to `data`.

Comment: yes it is possible, this is a handmade example for the post, not the real one. There is no mistake in the right, that's not the problem

Comment: There you have it, there is no more syntax error, I tested. This is not the problem because the result is still not good

Answer (score 0):

to fix the syntax error, change your list to something like this:

```
datas = [
    {
    '123':
        {
        'name': 'Adam',
        'nbgamesTot': 4,
        'winrateTot':100,
        'D1':
            {
            'nbgames' : 4,
            'nb_win' : 4,
            'winrate':100,
            },
        'D2': 'etc...,'
        }
    },
    {
    '456':
        {
        'name': 'Mark',
        'nbgamesTot': 4,
        'winrateTot':25,
        'D1':
            {
            'nbgames' : 4,
            'nb_win' : 1,
            'winrate':25,
            },
        'D2': 'etc...,'
        }
    },
    {
    '789':
        {
        'name': 'Yoko',
        'nbgamesTot': 4,
        'winrateTot':25,
        'D1':
            {
            'nbgames' : 4,
            'nb_win' : 1,
            'winrate':25
            },
        'D2': 'etc...,'
        }
    }
]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
The 'winrateTot' was formatted (2.f) before sorting, so considered to be type 'string'